# GET ToString then POST?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, rest

I have a button and in it I am trying to do a `GET` then a `POST` and I was wondering if some one could help me with the below code, what I am trying to do is set the `MessageID` into a string so I can use it for the `POST` `uriAddMessagetoGroup` ...

```
        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(uri1);
        var MessageID = xDoc.Descendants("Message")
            .Select(n => new
            {
                n.Element("MessageID").Value,
            })
            .ToString();

        string uriAddMessagetoGroup = string.Format("http://localhost:8000/Service/AddMessagetoGroup/{0}/{1}/{2}", textBox4.Text, MessageID, textBox21.Text);
```

Full code:

```
 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //Get the newly created message while the text is still in the textbox and find its messageID (int)
            string uri1 = "http://localhost:8000/Service/GetMessage/{anything}";
            string tagUri = uri1.Replace("{anything}", textBox21.Text);
            XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(tagUri);
            var MessageID = xDoc.Descendants("Message")
                   .Select(n => n.Element("MessageID").Value.ToString());

            //add the string to the uri and add the message to the relevant group while the group still exists in the textbox
            string uriAddMessagetoGroup = string.Format("http://localhost:8000/Service/AddMessagetoGroup/{0}/{1}/{2}", textBox4.Text, MessageID, textBox21.Text);
            byte[] arr2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(uriAddMessagetoGroup);
            HttpWebRequest req2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uriAddMessagetoGroup);
            req2.Method = "POST";
            req2.ContentType = "application/xml";
            req2.ContentLength = arr2.Length;
            Stream reqStrm2 = req2.GetRequestStream();
            reqStrm2.Write(arr2, 0, arr2.Length);
            reqStrm2.Close();
            HttpWebResponse resp2 = (HttpWebResponse)req2.GetResponse();
            MessageBox.Show(resp2.StatusDescription);
            reqStrm2.Close();
            resp2.Close();
```

Comment: @BeenishKhan  well Initially I thought it was my POST method but I took the post out and tested it seperate and it works but for some unknown reason the above doesnt? (Also tested the GET separately) so I can only think the ToString method isnt working...

Comment: My apologies but still not clear. What's not working ? What are you expecting to get and what are you actually getting ?

Comment: I am expecting to GET the `MessageID` belonging to a specific message then turn it into a `string` so I can use it as part of the `POST uri string`... and I am getting nothing.

Comment: Ok, that explains it. Can you share your XMl, most probably it's an issue with how you are trying to access the node.

Comment: @BeenishKhan Hi I have put the full code up while also using Anurags method but same again...

Comment: sorry I asked the wrong thing, can you share the data you are getting from uri1 ? string uri1 = "http://localhost:8000/Service/GetMessage/{anything}";
            string tagUri = uri1.Replace("{anything}", textBox21.Text);
            XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(uri1);

Comment: Its a number which is set to increment when ever a new message is created, or do you mean you would like to see my service code?

Comment: I actually need to see that XML. Are you saying it's just a number like 4 or 5 with no XML around it ? If that's the case then why are you using XDocument? You can just take the number. If you have proper XML then please share that, that's the thing I need to verify your LINQ statement

Comment: @BeenishKhan No It will have xml around it. Ok I posted xml and GET method and data contracts.

Comment: However this GET method already works.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 var MessageID = xDoc.Descendants("Message")
        .Select(n =>  n.Element("MessageID").Value.ToString());

 string uriAddMessagetoGroup = string.Format("http://localhost:8000/Service/AddMessagetoGroup/{0}/{1}/{2}", textBox4.Text, MessageID, textBox21.Text);
```

Comment: Hey still not working.... really strange :( +1 for the help tho. Will post full code.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to use FirstOrDefault()